# php session validation failing when called from page where session is not set

Tags: php, session

i am using session in my php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['RayaPromo']= "yes";
?>
```

this session will be set only for a particular flow. there is a common function FuncA.

funcA can be called from page A where session is set, or can be called from page B where session is not set.

the validation in funcA is failing every time whenever i call the function from page B where session is not set.

```
funcA(){
if(isset( $_SESSION['RayaPromo']))
            echo $_SESSION['RayaPromo'];
        else 
            echo 'empty';
}
```

Plz suggest. it doesn't show any error in the console. my buttons stop working!!!:(

Comment: Define *failing* - if a session "validation" function *fails* when there's no session, surely that's *working as intended* ?

Comment: You have to start session_start in every page where you want to use it. Best thing is that you cant start it in header.php and include header.php in every page of yours or if you don't have header.php then start session at top of every page.